# pyspark - Generate json from grouped data

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to group data from df and generate json object out of the grouped data. I thought I was on the right track but looking at the result I do not think I am generating a proper json object.

Source data

```
 df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
      ("20210924155828",'2021-09-17 13:55:35','2021-08-15 00:00:00','PRODUCT_04_20210815.DAT', '0.057','PRODUCT'), 
      ("20210924155828",'2021-09-17 13:55:35','2021-08-15 00:00:00','PRODUCT_00_20210815.DAT', '0.068','PRODUCT'), 
      ("20210924155828",'2021-09-17 13:55:35','2021-08-15 00:00:00','PRODUCT_01_20210815.DAT', '0.089','PRODUCT'), 
      ("20210924155828",'2021-09-17 13:55:35','2021-08-15 00:00:00','PRODUCT_03_20210815.DAT', '0.100','PRODUCT')
      ], ["ID", "FileReceivedTimestamp", "SourceDataTimestamp","SourceFileName", "FileSize","FileName"])

    df1.show()
    +--------------+---------------------+-------------------+--------------------+--------+--------+
    |            ID|FileReceivedTimestamp|SourceDataTimestamp|      SourceFileName|FileSize|FileName|
    +--------------+---------------------+-------------------+--------------------+--------+--------+
    |20210924155828|  2021-09-17 13:55:35|2021-08-15 00:00:00|PRODUCT_04_202108...|   0.057| PRODUCT|
    |20210924155828|  2021-09-17 13:55:35|2021-08-15 00:00:00|PRODUCT_00_202108...|   0.068| PRODUCT|
    |20210924155828|  2021-09-17 13:55:35|2021-08-15 00:00:00|PRODUCT_01_202108...|   0.089| PRODUCT|
    |20210924155828|  2021-09-17 13:55:35|2021-08-15 00:00:00|PRODUCT_03_202108...|   0.100| PRODUCT|
    +--------------+---------------------+-------------------+--------------------+--------+--------+
```

utilized to_json, groupBy, agg and collect_list to generate json object.

```
df2 = (df1.select("FileName","ID",to_json(struct("SourceFileName","FileReceivedTimestamp","FileSize")).alias("metadata"))
   .groupby("FileName","ID").agg(collect_list(col("metadata")).alias("jsonmetadata")))
```

I see below using display in databricks

[image]

to query and test my output i did a explode on the generated json. I get this error when trying to view SourceFileName "*Can't extract value from MetadataArray#779: need struct type but got string;"*

```
display(df2.select(explode(col("jsonmetadata")).alias("MetadataArray")
                  ,col("MetadataArray.SourceFileName").alias("SourceFileName")
                  ))
```

Am I missing something here.... was hoping to query the data after exploding using MetadataArray.SourceFileName, MetadataArray.FileSize etc...

**Edit:**
My expectation was to get jsonmetadata as array of struct instead of array of string.  removing to_json helped resolve my issue.

```
df2 = (df1.select("FileName","ID",(struct("SourceFileName","FileReceivedTimestamp","FileSize")).alias("metadata"))
   .groupby("FileName","ID").agg(collect_list(col("metadata")).alias("jsonmetadata")))
```

Schema after removing to_json conversion.

> root  |-- FileName: string (nullable = true)  |-- ID: string (nullable
> = true)  |-- jsonmetadata: array (nullable = true)  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)  |    |    |-- SourceFileName: string
> (nullable = true)  |    |    |-- FileReceivedTimestamp: string
> (nullable = true)  |    |    |-- FileSize: string (nullable = true)

[image]

Comment: Seems like your query is working fine. Do you actually want to group by on FileName and ID or SourceFileName and ID? Can you please add your expected df2 as well?

Answer (score 2):

Since `MetadataArray` values are json strings, you need to parse them using `from_json` function with the correct schema

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, explode, from_json

sch = "SourceFileName string, FileReceivedTimestamp string, FileSize string"

df2\
.select(explode(col("jsonmetadata")).alias("MetadataArray"), 
        from_json(col("MetadataArray"), sch).getField("SourceFileName").alias("SourceFileName"))\
.show()

# +--------------------+--------------------+
# |       MetadataArray|      SourceFileName|
# +--------------------+--------------------+
# |{"SourceFileName"...|PRODUCT_04_202108...|
# |{"SourceFileName"...|PRODUCT_00_202108...|
# |{"SourceFileName"...|PRODUCT_01_202108...|
# |{"SourceFileName"...|PRODUCT_03_202108...|
# +--------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, apply the schema worked. However after rehashing I realized to_json was not necessary. with to_json i was getting array of string instead of array of structs.